# Getting answer for unanswered (already asked by someone else) question on Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

What should I do, if I have some issues and when searching on a Stack Exchange site, I found that the same question is already asked by someone else, but yet not answered (or answered but that's not accepted)?

If I ask the question it would be an exact duplicate at that Stack Exchange site.
(I do not have enough reputation to comment, or to put bounties on the asked question.)